# Need a calendar control for iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, user-controls, calendar

Does anyone know where I can find a ready to use calendar control (open source or library) that looks more or less like the calendar found in the built in iPhone app?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you need to accomplish, you can either use the new EventKit framework in 4.0, which gives you the ability to create events in the users calendar, or you can use an open source calendar view such as the one found in Tapku Library http://github.com/devinross/tapkulibrary